# Exchange limits of definite integrals of the form $\int_t^{T} f(u) \int_0^{u} g(s) ds du$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If I have a definite integral of the form $$
\int_t^{T} f(u) \left[ \int_0^{u} g(s) ds \right] du
$$

Where $t,T$ are constants. How can I exchange the limits of integration, if at all possible? I can see that the expression in square brackets is basically a function $h(u) = \int_0^{u} g(s) ds $ of $u$ so I have a feeling I cannot exchange the limits, but maybe I am missing something. Could the structure of $f,g$ somehow help?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. The region of integration is the trapezoid with base the segment $[t,T]$ on the $u$-axis, vertical bases and the other leg on the diagonal $u=s$. To change the order of integration, you notice that the range of $s$ is $[0,T]$. The limits for $u$ given $s$ depend on whether $s\in[0,t]$ or $s\in[t,T]$. If you draw the trapezoidal region, you should easily see that you get
$$
\int\limits_0^tg(s)[\int\limits_t^Tf(u)du]\,ds+\int\limits_t^Tg(s)[\int\limits_s^Tf(u)du]\,ds
$$

Comment: It seems to work, thanks for that! I am not sure I am clear on how to draw the trapezoid from this though, are you sure the bases are vertical instead of horizontal ?

Comment: nevermind, I see it now. Thanks !